# How do I make all rows (arrays) include the same set of keys?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a set of arrays created from my database and I want to transform them so that I can print them to a table. Each array describes a product's FEATURE and VALUE.But not all products have the same length of features. For instance:

```
array("Main Colour"=>"Red","Minor Colour"=>"Blue","Size"=>"Large")
array("Main Colour"=>"Red","Size"=>"Small")
```

So, the first product has the FEATURE "Minor Colour", but the second does not. I would like to transform the arrays so that they each include the same keys even if there is no value assigned. As below.

```
array("Main Colour"=>"Red","Minor Colour"=>"Blue","Size"=>"Large")
array("Main Colour"=>"Red","Minor Colour"=>"","Size"=>"Small")
```

I need (I think I need) each array to be the same length so that I can loop through each product to create a row, and then loop through each feature to create a column.

There might be hundreds of product arrays, so I'm looking for something that isn't simply comparing one array to the other.

Thanks!

Comment: The best solution would be to fix your data access layer so that it properly returns properties with "empty" (does that equal `null` in your case?) values normally. Failing that, if you don't want to hardcode the full set of property names how do you propose to actually discover what that is without enumerating over *all* results? Even if you do that, what if the consumer of the data expects to read some property that happens to not exist on any of your actual rows?

Comment: So, you should either fix the DAL or modify the consumer to properly handle missing keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know from the start just how many possible different features exist in your entire product set, then it might be helpful to do a first pass through all of your products in the array to obtain a full set of possible features.

Then, you do a second pass through the array and, for each product - if it doesn't have some of the features that are your feature list, add those features (with empty string value) to that product.

Here's what the code would look like:

```
// Assuming that you have $products, which is an array of arrays.
// Each element of $products is an associated array that contains
// various feature-value pairs.
$feature_list = array();
foreach($products as $product) {
  $feature_list = array_unique(array_merge($feature_list, array_keys($product)));
}

foreach($products as &$product) {
  foreach($feature_list as $key) {
    if (!array_key_exists($key, $product)) {
      $product[$key] = '';
    }
  }
}

print_r($products);
```

Granted, this may not be the most optimal/efficient way to do things.  But it's clear and straightforward.

Here are links to documentation for various PHP functions used:

- [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)
- [`array_unique`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)
- [`array_keys`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)
- [`array_key_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php)

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `array_key_exists` and then add on if not exists !

### Generalized Code

```
<?php
$arr1=array("Main Colour"=>"Red","Minor Colour"=>"","Size"=>"Small","Major Colour"=>"Yellow");
$arr2=array("Main Colour"=>"Red");

$allKeys = array_keys($arr1); //<--- Pass the array which has all the keys !

function checkArrHasKey($allKeys,&$arr2) //<---- arg passed as a reference
{
foreach($allKeys as $val)
 {
    if(!array_key_exists($val,$arr2))
    {
        $arr2[$val]='';
    }
}
}
checkArrHasKey($allKeys,$arr2); //<--- Pass the first arg as the $allKeys and second arg as your array
print_r($arr2);
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
Array
(
    [Main Colour] => Red
    [Minor Colour] => 
    [Size] => 
    [Major Colour] => 
)
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/100958)

Comment: This is not a good solution, but if you wanted to do it anyway `$arr2 += ['Minor Colour' => '']` would be much simpler.

Comment: Thanks Shankar, but I'm looking for a solution where I don't need to know what the keys are. Also, I need to be able to apply this to hundreds of rows.

Comment: @MatthewAndrianakos, Please see the new edited answer along with the demo , Also the code has been commented for your reference.